# C++ Why in one case saving to file is working and another not?

Tags: c++

Need some help over here, can somone explain me why this is working :

```
void change_boss()
    {
        string password;
        fstream file;



        cout << "Type new password" << endl;
        cin >> password;
        file.open("admin_list.txt");
        file << password;
        file.close();

    };
```

and this is not working ?

```
void change_worker()
    {
        string pass;
        fstream file;


        cout << "Type new password" << endl;
        cin >> pass;
        file.open("worker_list.txt");
        file >> pass;
        file.close();

    };
```

Any idea ? Coz I have no idea whats wrong with that

Comment: Should be like this      file << pass; but its still not working

Comment: Looks like you have the `<<` operator reversed in the second case with `file >> pass;`

Comment: Copy and paste your actual code and the way you're calling it.

Comment: Just for sanity, how about you validate your IO operations actually *worked*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong operator; Your second block should instead replace this:

```
file >> pass;
```

with:

```
file << pass;
```

If you do not need *both* read and write access to a file, please instead consider using `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` for read-only and write-only operations respectively.